# google sheets - is there a way to "instance" cell formatting?

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, formatting, instance, conditional-formatting

I have 2 sheets:

In **Sheet1!A1:A** is a list of values, the cells have formatting to color them appropriately.

In **Sheet2!A1:A** is the formula:  "**={Sheet1!A1:A}**"

This instances the cell values, but not the formatting. Is there a way to get the formatting to carry through to sheet 2 also?

Answer (score 2):

you have only 3 options:

- use script
- hardcode the formatting with <kbd>CTRL + C</kbd> followed by <kbd>CTRL + ALT + V</kbd>

  [image]
- or to setup Conditional formatting based on Sheet1

  (in this case you will need to reference `Sheet1!A1` as `INDIRECT("Sheet1!A1")`)

Comment: Thanks player0, I think setting the conditions on sheet1 makes the most sense in my case. Thank you!